# LeoFS returns a nodedown error but the node appears to be running

Tags: s3cmd

I am running leofs 1.2.22 on a single node. Everything was working ok but when I started leofs today I am unable to list the contents of any buckets. I am getting errors stating the node is down.

A leofs-adm status shows

```
$ leofs-adm status
[System Confiuration]
-----------------------------------+----------
 Item                              | Value    
-----------------------------------+----------
 Basic/Consistency level
-----------------------------------+----------
                    system version | 1.2.22
                        cluster Id | leofs_1
                             DC Id | dc_1
                    Total replicas | 1
          number of successes of R | 1
          number of successes of W | 1
          number of successes of D | 1
 number of rack-awareness replicas | 0
                         ring size | 2^128
-----------------------------------+----------
 Multi DC replication settings
-----------------------------------+----------
        max number of joinable DCs | 2
           number of replicas a DC | 1
-----------------------------------+----------
 Manager RING hash
-----------------------------------+----------
                 current ring-hash | 433fe365
                previous ring-hash | 433fe365
-----------------------------------+----------

 [State of Node(s)]
  -------+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------  -----+----------------------------
 type  |           node           |    state     |  current ring  |   prev     ring    |          updated at         
-------+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------------
  S    | storage_0@127.0.0.1      | running      | 433fe365       | 433fe365       | 2017-06-27 01:00:50 -0400
  G    | gateway_0@127.0.0.1      | running      | 433fe365       | 433fe365       | 2017-10-09 06:49:48 -0400
-------+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------------
```

This shows the storage node is running. However if checking the details of the storage node it returns

```
$ leofs-adm du storage_0@127.0.0.1
[ERROR] nodedown
```

I tried to recover the node but this also fails

```
 $ leofs-adm recover-node storage_0@127.0.0.1 
 [ERROR] Could not connect
```

I am able to list the buckets

```
$ leofs-adm get-buckets
cluster id   | bucket                  | owner  | permissions                             | created at                
-------------+-------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------
leofs_1      | workflow            | simon  | Me(full_control)                           | 2017-06-28 20:47:08 -0400
leofs_1      | weather             | simon  | Me(full_control)                       | 2017-06-26 08:27:26 -0400
leofs_1      | workers             | simon  | Me(full_control), Everyone(read,write) | 2017-06-26 08:30:30 -0400
```

But I am unable to list the contents of any bucket

```
$ s3cmd ls s3://weather/
WARNING: Retrying failed request: /?delimiter=/
WARNING: 500 (InternalError): We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
WARNING: Waiting 3 sec...
WARNING: Retrying failed request: /?delimiter=/
WARNING: 500 (InternalError): We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
```

I am not sure how to recover the node and have not found anything online to help. Updating the version of leofs is not an option as I was unable to get Python boto2 to communicate with a later version of LeoFS.

Regards

Simon

Comment: Cause was a leveldb database was corrupted. Ran a repair db and it is now working.